# Java Array with point (coordination)

Tags: java, arrays, initialization, declaration

i want to creat an array in the main method containing point
like `p={(3,8),(2,8)}`
with this class

```
public class Point
{
    private float x,y;

    public Point(){}
    public Point(float abs){this.x=abs;}
    public Point(float abs, float ord){this.x=abs; this.y=ord;}
    public void setPoint(float abs, float ord){this.x=abs; this.y=ord;}
}
```

I used `p[1] = new Point(5,6);` but when i tried to call `p[1].x` i found that x has a private access.
any idea.

Comment: It's private because you have it set as a private variable (`private float x, y;`). Either make it public or (the correct way) create a get method to get the value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create an array of `Point`s like this:

```
Point[] points = new Point[] {
    new Point(3,8),
    new Point(2,8)
};
```

& in order to be able to access the `x` & `y` member variables, they should have a `public` identifier.

```
public class Point{
    public float x,y;
    ...
}
```

But the most optimal way to proceed is by creating a *getter*:

```
public class Point{
    private float x,y;
    ...

    public float getX() { return x; }
    public float getY() { return y; }
}
```

then you can access the `Point`'s `x` & `y` this way :

```
Point point = new Point(1,1);
point.getX();
point.getY();
```

Comment: I would opt for a getter rather than a public access modifier